# AlertDialog like permission dialog in Android TV (Leanback) App

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-tv, leanback

I'm working on an Android TV project which is a leanback project basically.

**I want to show an alert dialog similar to the permission dialog in android tv apps.** see the image.

[image: permission dialog in android tv app]

I tried adding normal AlertDialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
alert.show();
```

but that doesn't help. Can anyone show me the way to show similar AlertDialog in Android TV app?

Comment: You probably need to use a custom layout for this

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution and created a custom DialogFragment, Look at [github](https://github.com/Tiarait/DialogLikeLeanback)

And now I can create the dialog I need like this

```
val dialogExit = LeanbackDialogFragment(R.string.dialog_exit, R.string.dialog_exit_d, R.drawable.ic_exit)
dialogExit.addButton(R.string.yes) { dialog, which ->
    exitProcess(0)
}
dialogExit.addButton(R.string.no)
dialogExit.addButton("I don't know")
dialogExit.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager)
```

---

Result

[image]

Comment: This is great! I will check this solution in my sample repository and will accept the answer if this works well.

Comment: @Tiarait Can you please make a java version of the ```LeanbackDialogFragment.kt```?