# Android TV alert dialog box; New design

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-tv, android-8.1-oreo

As you know the dialog for asking permission in Android TV Oreo+ is like this:

[image: Dialog box in ATV]

It should reside in frameworks part of AOSP. (Am I right?) Anyone know the class path of this component. I think using this dialog in android TV apps is nicer to everybody!

Comment: Now I know if we add "leanback" and "leanback_only" features to our AOSP build, the regular dialogs will appear like above.

Comment: I didn't find a solution and created a custom DialogFragment https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093344/7540461

Comment: @Tiarait Can you please make a java version of the ```LeanbackDialogFragment.kt```